# Scala Spark - Select columns by name and list

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to select columns from a Scala Spark DataFrame using both single column names and names extracted from a List. My current solutions looks like:

```scala
var cols_list = List("d", "e")

df
.select(
    col("a"),
    col("b"),
    col("c"),
    cols_list.map(col): _*)
```

However, it throws an error:

```
<console>:81: error: no `: _*' annotation allowed here
(such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)
               cols_list.map(col): _*
                                        ^
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select` accepts a `List[Column]`, so you need to construct and provide that list, e.g.

```
df.select(col("a") :: col("b") :: col("c") :: cols_list.map(col): _*)
```

Comment: Hi, your code throws the following error: <console>:88: error: value :: is not a member of Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column]
               col("a") :: col("b") :: col("c") :: cols_list.map(col): _*
                                                                                    ^

Comment: didn't you define cols_list as `var cols_list = List("d", "e")`?

Comment: it shouldn't be an array - should be a list

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem! For the MWE I wrote is as a list, but in the original code I had it defined as `another_df.columns` so it was an Array. I modified it to `another_df.columns.toList` and now your code works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine for me, you can also use the $ notation.

```
scala> df.select(cols_list.map(col):_*)
res8: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [d: int, e: int]

scala> df.select(cols_list.map(c => $"$c"):_*)
res9: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [d: int, e: int]
```

Maybe you just need to `import spark.implicits._`

EXTRA: Also check your variable  names, it's a [naming convention](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html) in scala to use camel case and try to [avoid var](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/2-language-rules.md#22-should-use-immutable-data-structures) (this is just a good practise issue, not related to your error at all)

```
val colsList = List("d", "e")
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, just starting with Scala coming from Python so I'll keep that in mind. I also imported spark.implicits._ but it still shows the error